# Why QGIS cannot open government KML for health authority boundaries?

Tags: qgis, kml

When I try to load [health authority boundaries](https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/7bc6018f-bb4f-4e5d-845e-c529e3d1ac3b/resource/29b60929-1c98-4b46-bd26-046959defbf5) from the Government of Canada data site into QGIS I get the following message:

[image]

I have checked on two systems and I get the same result. Mind you, one is Archlinux and the other is Ubuntu, if that matters. This is the info for the Ubuntu system:

```bash
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

And the Archlinux system:
`Linux orcus 6.4.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 03 Aug 2023 16:02:01 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I am using QGIS 3.32 Lima.

Comment: Next thing I'm going to try is loading some other KML files, especially from an independent source giving different information.

Comment: Kml is a bad transfer format, see if you can find a better one on their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are network linked kmls that go to a server (geoserver?)

https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1

```
<img src='https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetLegendGraphic&layer=pub:WHSE_ADMIN_BOUNDARIES.BCHA_HEALTH_AUTHORITY_BNDRY_SP&style=372_373&format=image/png'><br>
```

you can use the wms service in QGIS.

[image]